# Contour plot of a sequence of spheres with increasing radius

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to do a simple thing really, plot a sequence of spheres with increasing radii and I used a Do-loop to do it, but nothing happens, Please suggest what I can do to get the result I want?

```
Do[
  ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == i, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}],  
  {i, 0, 10}]
```

It should be a series of spheres almost side by side

See the image; the spheres should be stepped with different origins.

[image]

Comment: What is your desired end goal? An animation of some sort? Or perhaps all on the same graph? We can help! Welcome to Mma.SE. As a start, `Do` does not actually return anything unless explicitly informed to do so.

Comment: I have told Do to do a ContourPlot3D. I want simply a sequence of spheres with increasing radius in a 3D plot as mentioned.

Comment: Right right, so `Do` wasn’t told to `Return` that evaluation. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html): “Unless an explicit `Return` is used, the value returned by `Do` is `Null`.” Are you trying to `Show` a sequence of these on the same plot at the same time? Or output sequence of them in a `List`, such as with a `Table`? You could also `Animate` the sequence, or wrap it in a `Manipulate` so you have control over it!

Comment: That is okay it sort of does what I want but I do not want manipulation but a superposition all spheres but they have changing origin, so that they are almost side by side

Answer (score 12):

### Equally spaced radii

```
spacing = 1;
radii = spacing Range[10];
ClearAll[tr]
tr[n_] := (n^2 - 1) / 2 / spacing;
```

You can use `tr` and `radii` with

#### [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[(x - tr[#])^2 + y^2 == #^2 & /@ radii],
  {x, -1, 65}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> Automatic,  Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 1 -> 5]
```

[image]

#### [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{# Cos[t] + tr@#, # Sin[t]} & /@ radii], 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False,
 Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 1 -> 5]
```

> same picture

#### [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

```
Graphics[{Thick, ColorData[97]@#, Circle[{tr@#, 0}, #]} & /@ radii]
```

> same picture

#### [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html)

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[(x - tr[#])^2 + y^2 + z^2 == #^2 & /@ radii], 
   {x, -1, 65}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -15, 15}, 
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5], BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   ViewPoint -> Front, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False , PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

#### [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{# Cos[u] Sin[v] + tr@#, # Sin[u] Sin[v], # Cos[  v]} & /@ radii],
  {v, 0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

> same picture

#### [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
styles = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
    (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ContourPlot3D]);

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], styles[[#]], Sphere[{tr @ #, 0, 0}, #]} & /@ radii, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

> same picture

### Random Radii

To get horizontal coordinates of the centers of the circles/spheres (1) Accumulate the diameters of circles/spheres in odd and even positions separately, (2) shift the second list by an arbitrary amount (by the average of the horizontal positions the two leftmost circles/spheres below), (3) riffle the two lists and (4) subtract the radii from the resulting list:

```
SeedRandom[1]
randomradii = RandomSample[Range @ 20, 10];
centers = Module[{origins = {0, Mean[Sort[#][[{1, 2}]]]}}, Riffle @@ 
 (Function[x, origins[[x]] + Accumulate[2 #[[x ;; ;; 2]]]] /@ {1, 2}) - #] &@ randomradii;
```

Using `centers` and `randomradii` with `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`:

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[{Thick, ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], 
  Circle[{centers[[#2[[1]]]], 0}, #]} &, randomradii]]

Graphics3D[MapIndexed[{Opacity[.5], ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], 
   Sphere[{centers[[#2[[1]]]], 0, 0}, #]} &, randomradii], 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

With sorted radii, for example,

```
SeedRandom[1]
randomradii = Sort@ RandomChoice[Range @ 20, 10];
```

we get

[image]

Comment: Can this be done without the use of Sphere[]?

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D` and `ContourPlot3D` do not use `Sphere[]`

Comment: Excellent work, it gives me a starting point for what I want to do - thank you.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comments, `Do` does not return the plots. But why not just use Manipulate? This is what Manipulate meant for.

[image]

```
Manipulate[

 Module[{x, y, z, max},
  max = 10;
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r^2, {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max}, {z, -max, max}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-max, max}, {-max, max}, {-max, max}}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   SphericalRegion -> True]
  ],

 {{r,5,"radius"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled",ContinuousAction->False},
 TrackedSymbols :> {r}
 ]
```

But if you really just need static 3D plots, you can do

```
makePlot[r_] := Module[{x, y, z, max},
   max = 10;
   ContourPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r^2, {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max}, {z, -max, max},
    PlotRange -> {{-max, max}, {-max, max}, {-max, max}},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", SphericalRegion -> True,
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"Radius ", r}]]
   ];

   Grid[Partition[Table[makePlot[r], {r, 1, 9}], 3], Frame -> All,
```

Spacings -> {1, 1}]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To update for the new requirements posted:

```
makePlot[r_] := Module[{x, y, z, max},
   Sphere[{r^2 - 1, 0, 0}, r]
   ];
tab = Table[makePlot[r], {r, 1, 4}]
Graphics3D[tab, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: See below I uploaded an image

Comment: Nice answer! +1 I think the OP has defined their needs a bit more, though you’ll likely be able to accommodate quite considerably with these!

Comment: Can this be done without the use of the Sphere[] function?